# How to create a border that does't add a margin?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, border, margin

I'm new to HTML/CSS, and I'm learning Bootstrap.

I'm coding a Bootstrap navbar and I have a small difficulty, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djuj5jte/) of the work I have done.

In the HTML code there is the normal markup that goes into building a TWBS navbar, and I have added code to change the color of the active tab:

```
.navbar-nav a.active {
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    -o-transition: .2s;
    transition: .2s;
    border-top: 2px solid #212121;
}
```

**Problem:** The text wrapped within the`<a>` tag is now slightly pushed down and I am noticing that the `border-top` CSS property functions more like a `margin-top` property.

How do I avoid this and create a border that doesn't add the margin?

Comment: @everyone , thaks for the upvotes , it really encourages me .. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can style `:before` pseudo element of the active `a` and position it relatively to the parent element:

```
.navbar-nav a.active:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/djuj5jte/5/

Comment: right on the money !!!! BUUUUT , i am running on IE 8 :D ... and not to mention the OS that web devs love ... XP :D ... also i am already using psudo elements for a transition . BTW , is't box-border supposed to make the border not act like a margin ??

Comment: `:before` is supported in IE8 so it should work. As for `border-box`.. theoretically yes, but practically I can't make it work in this case with border-box for some reason.

Comment: @dfsq , border-box won't work  i believe because there's no height set. another way round is to set the border from the beginning and transparent  or via rgba(). http://jsfiddle.net/djuj5jte/6/

Answer (score 4):

You could use an inset box shadow:

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 0px 0px #212121;
```

This has the benefit of not changing the elements size OR requiring a pseudo element but sadly isn't supported in <=IE8 ;(

See: http://jsfiddle.net/djuj5jte/3/

Comment: Nice! However IE8 won't understand it.

Comment: Poop! I didn't see the IE8 requirement. In which case my vote goes to @dfsq's answer.

Comment: Thanks! I actually think your approach is better if IE8 is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

so that the border will be part of the element width.

**Useful link**: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Ok I see from your comment on the previous answer that you are using it :)

Comment: Make sure that the link is either display block or inline-block :)

Comment: Why inline-block or block